# js to password-protect directories

Tags: javascript, password-protection

Is it possible to password protect (from website users) certain directories on a server? It doesn't have to be secure as it's only meant to prevent learners from downloading/accessing materials from other courses. The learners are not very tech-savvy so it's not a big deal.

Say I have directories with 3 courses:
    /course1
    /course2
    /course3

and I'd like each directory to have its own password so I can email learners doing course1 its url and password.
How would I do it? I have a very limited access to the server so client side is the only option.

Comment: One idea is to encrypt the `index.html` page in each directory using JavaScript and a unique password. Then you could link to each of the resources in the directory from the index page. Check out my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31013664/2234742) for details.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister While that’s a cool idea for single pages, I don’t see how you could protect a whole directory using this technique without having to reenter the password all the time. (You could of course store the password in the local storage but...)

Comment: @idmean You're correct, it wouldn't protect the whole directory, only the URLs, which means security wouldn't be great.

Comment: This cannot be done client side. You have to configure the server to require authentication for specific directories.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister I took your idea a step further. If you are interested take a look at my answer below.

Comment: @FelixKling Without talking about implementation details, encryption makes it possible client-side.

Comment: What server are you using? Apache? Look into `.htaccess` documentation, it's trivial to set up a password for a directory. **Do not use javascript for password protection**, unless you are well versed in it and know what you are doing (serverside js, clientside decryption of documents etc, though all of these solutions are way over your head).

Answer (score 4):

[Download the example here.](https://github.com/idmean/JSDicrypt)

Thinking about Maximillian Laumeister’s idea I came up with this. This may not be a perfect solution but should work.

You store all resources on the server encrypted, encoded as base64 in plain text files. Separated by a comma you prepend the desired mime type. E.g.

- `main`: (`CryptoJS.AES.encrypt('<a href="http://localhost:8080/_/more">Read more</a>', "hello").toString();`)

  ```
  text/html;U2FsdGVkX19Tdq6V7swK/7NgnwR8JgZ1dYZEkfT9hx+QKzFrpyqKeuo0Tv25ozYkAxIIt65G9DKmOYU6tmZ0Dp/I4BuopQ/3xHClB+K+BX8=
  ```
- `more`: (`CryptoJS.AES.encrypt('<h1>More</h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>', "hello").toString();`)

  ```
  text/html;U2FsdGVkX19GdZ+SRQ9vM2Amiyu0OqOOSX7X5IOCcLfHMpHHgI0h/mxS8iuUggfqmFBN+yXy53z445ZW1mAlHQ==
  ```

**In hyperlinks you have to place something in URLs (`_/`) causing a 404 which can be removed later on** and you have to specify the protocol including the server. This is the only way the script can intercept the request, stop it, request the correct URL and decode the response. (The 404 is needed because browsers will otherwise download the specified file directly and will not call the `load` event handlers.)

You then create an `index.html` page which contains an iframe and requests the user to enter a password which is then kept in some scope so that no XSS attack could retrieve the value.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe id="theIframe"></iframe>
        <script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This allows you to request an URL, decode the received base64 content and try to decrypt it with the given password. You would then set the decrypted content as the iframe’s content via a data URL.

```
(function(){
    var iframe = document.getElementById("theIframe");
    var password = prompt("Enter the password!");
    var allowEvent = true;

    function presentURL(url){
        allowEvent = false;
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.addEventListener("load", function(){

            var splitters = this.responseText.split(";", 2);
            var type = splitters[0];
            var encrypted = splitters[1];

            var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, password).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8); //Decrypt
            var data = window.btoa(decrypted); //Encode the decrypted data into base64

            iframe.src = "data:" + type + ";base64," + data;

        });
        req.open("GET", url);
        req.send();
    }

    presentURL("/main");

    iframe.addEventListener("load", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if (allowEvent){
            iframe.contentWindow.stop();
            //remove the 404 cause and call presentURL
            presentURL(iframe.contentWindow.location.href.replace(/_\//, ""));
        }
        else {
            allowEvent = true;
        }
    });
})();
```

The above example uses [CryptoJS](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) and may not work across browsers!

**This code actually works!**

Comment: Thank you everyone. I'm going to play with it over the next couple of days.

Answer (score -1):

If you care zero about security this could be done in a few ways. Here is a rough example to get you thinking about the logic you may need for this;

Consider the following code:

```js
var password = '12345678';

function showBody() {
    
    // Password matches?
    if ( document.getElementById( 'code' ).value == password ) {
      
        // Show secret stuff and hide password box
        document.getElementById( 'container' ).style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById( 'code' ).style.display = 'none';
    }
}

document.body.onload = function () {
  
    // Hide the secret stuff
    document.getElementById( 'container' ).style.display = 'none';
  
    // Create a password box
    var input  = document.createElement( 'input' );
    input.setAttribute( 'type', 'password' );
    input.setAttribute( 'id', 'code' );
  
    // Append the password box
    document.body.appendChild( input );
  
    // Listen for the password
    document.addEventListener( 'keyup', showBody, false );
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id = 'container'>
        I am hidden
    </div>
</body>
```

Keep in mind there is more than one way to do this. This is simply an example so you can get started writing your code and get the general idea of how the logic for this type of thing **could** be done. It is very insecure and you should definitely consider other solutions from the server.

Comment: The question asks about protection, so any answer which starts with "if you care zero about security" is off topic.

Comment: The question is ambiguous in nature seeing as the next line says " It doesn't have to be secure"

Comment: Still, one should never recommend insecure approaches. This is about as secure as "Tell them not to look in the other directories" or "Don't tell them the urls of the other courses".

Comment: The answer provided, provides the answer to what the OP is asking in specific context to the entire question asked. If the OP does not need something to be a certain way, it is not my goal to force my ideals on them. It would be different if he did not say "It doesnt have to be secure" but he did say that, and in that context, the provided answer is perfectly valid. The answer follows the guidelines of the question validly and accurately. A downvote for the reason of "security" is someone expecting their ideals to be forced onto others based on what they consider the OP needs, not wants.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I'm going to play with it over the next couple of days